# "They're not" vs. "they aren't"

Tags: meaning, grammar, contractions, negation

How dissimilar are "they're not" and "they aren't"?
Is it dependent on context or are these exactly the same?

> They are supposed to be going, but they are not.
>   They are not going.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are pretty much equivalent. If you desire to place more emphasis on the negative, use "They're not."

Comment: I think the difference is more a verbal tic than anything else. When I speak I usually contract the first two words (They're not vs. they aren't, it's not vs. it isn't) etc. When writing I do the opposite.