# "It isn't" versus "it's not"

Tags: differences, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“It isn't” versus “it's not”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/it-isnt-versus-its-not)

Is there any difference in meaning, or supposed impression when hearing it?