# "It isn't" or "It's not"

Tags: contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“It isn't” versus “it's not”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/it-isnt-versus-its-not)

When contracting "It is not Tuesday" are there any grammatical reasons to use either:

"It's not Tuesday"

or

"It isn't Tuesday"

If not, what do you prefer?