# "It isn't" vs "It is not" (Google suggestion) - which one is more common?

Tags: abbreviations

Everyone agrees that:

> Semantically "It's not" and "It isn't" mean the same thing: "It is
>   not".

No doubt here. See: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110704115859AAmQmxZ

The reason why I'm asking is because Google is suggesting one way regardless the fact the one other one has more hits, see: ["that isn't my problem"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=that%20isn%27t%20my%20problem&oq=tha&aqs=chrome.1.57j59l2j61j0j62.3082j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22that%20isn%27t%20my%20problem%22&nfpr=1&sa=X&ei=7BHpUd3dJeHX0QXl5YGoBw&ved=0CCsQvgUoAQ&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=d88672e609cf611f&biw=1335&bih=1666) and ["that's not my problem"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=that%20isn%27t%20my%20problem&oq=tha&aqs=chrome.1.57j59l2j61j0j62.3082j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#nfpr=1&q=%22that%27s%20not%20my%20problem%22&spell=1&sa=X&ei=8hHpUbOIN8aZ0AWE_oDwDA&ved=0CCoQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49478099,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.c75bKy5EQ0A.O&fp=d88672e609cf611f&biw=1335&bih=1666)

[image]

In general: which one is **more common** and what examples where it **makes difference** come to your mind?

Comment: Please refer to this question [“It isn't” vs. “it's not”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/it-isnt-vs-its-not). Your question appears to be a duplicate of the earlier question and is likely to be closed unless you have a specific issue not addressed by the earlier question. If so, please revise your question accordingly.

Comment: Please clarify your question (in the light of my above comment). The title says "**It** isn't v. **It's** not". Your question says "**that** isn't v. **that's** not".

Comment: Yeah, it's a duplicate. I was mostly concerned about Google suggestion tool --> why does it recommend one way over another?

Comment: I guess that's a question for Google and analysis of the results. I don't know how accurate their initial 'hits counter' is. Also, I note that the first page of one of the lists has multiple references to the lyrics of a particular song. Things like that can, of course, skew hit search results.

Answer (score 0):

I would feel "That isn't my problem" tends to suggest "My problem is a different one" slightly more than "That's not my problem" which tends to suggest "That is somebody else's problem".

The two clearly overlap.

Comment: When speaking, the two meanings can conveyed quite clearly using either phrasing by which words you stress.

Comment: @Peter - Sometimes spoken stress may not help: "**That's** not my problem" and "That's not **my** problem" seem clearer to me than "That's **not** my problem"