# "You aren't in" vs. "You're not in"

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“They are not”: “they're not” versus “they aren't”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14748/they-are-not-theyre-not-versus-they-arent)

I noticed that *you aren't in* and *you're not in* are two ways to shorten *you are not in*.

Are they always interchangeable? Are there situations where you would choose one over the other?

Answer (score 6):

Both mean the same thing. However using *you're not* seems to me to place more emphasis on the negation in speech because of the solitary *not*.

Another reason to use *you're not* would be that the listener would less likely mistake *aren't* for *are* in a noisy place for example.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with the idea that there's some meaningful difference in emphasis between the two forms, and I don't think there are really any contexts where they're not interchangeable.

The main difference is simply that *You're not* is [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20%27%20re%20not,you%20aren%20%27%20t&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3). I think that's just because we usually start by contracting at the first available point. We haven't consciously registered that there's another potential contraction point immediately following - we can only use one or the other, so usually we're already committed to the first one before the second comes along.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This question has been discussed a few times on various grammar & language websites.  At [answers.yahoo.com](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090701165525AAjDcND) the concensus is:

> When expanded, these represent the same words: *you are not*. In that regard, there's no difference.
> Keep in mind that neither expression should be used in formal writing because contractions are considered somewhat informal.

At [wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=829253) one poster rants against "*we aren't, they aren't, you aren't etc.*; while another writes: "*We're not going* stresses the not.
*We aren't going* does not stress anything"; and a third argues by analogy with *I'm not* being preferred to  *I amn't* or *I ain't*.

The longer thread of comments at [reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/7h6yt/grammar_nazi_help_youre_not_or_you_arent/) seems more useful than the two references already mentioned; it gives several examples are given where one form may be more natural than the other, such as:

> a: I'm a computer programmer. b: No, you're not.
>
> a: I'm going home now.  b: No, you aren't.

The reddit thread includes examples of different emphases (much as before), and also digresses into inconclusive mention of *You'rn't, You'ren't*, and *shouldn't've*.

Answer (score 1):

It's purely a stylistic choice as they both use different contractions to shorten the same sentence.

> You are not in...