# Is "You're not" or "You aren't" better for contraction usage of "You are not"?

Tags: formality, negation, contractions, negative-raising

Basically the title; is it better to use "You're not" or "You aren't" in place of "You are not" in formal writing?

Comment: If it's formal writing, you are generally advised not to use contractions at all.

Comment: sorry, not necessarily formal writing, just not like full on slang

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["You aren't in" vs. "You're not in"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47404/you-arent-in-vs-youre-not-in)

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate so that you can read those to get more information, but as worded your question lacks sufficient context necessary for anyone here ever to come up with concrete guidance that will apply to all possible situations. The cadence and the emphasis will vary, and that therefore requires understanding the speaker's intent for any particular situation.  As AlexB wrote in the duplicate, this is a lot more complex that it may appear.